# Is there a way to print all the parameters of the objects created in the __init__ method?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

This is the code I'm working on. I created some users, giving them a name, surname and a value.

Is there a way to return and print all, for instance, name of every user I created?

```
class Bacheca:

    def __init__(self, name, surname, value):
        self.name = name
        self.surname = surname
        self.value = value

user1 = Bacheca("John", "Black", 1)
user2 = Bacheca("Mark", "Green", 2)
user3 = Bacheca("Phil", "White", 3)
```

What I would like it's to print, for example, all the name of each users:

```
John 
Mark
Phil
```

Is it possibile?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Keep track of the users and `print(user.name)`? What exactly is the difficulty you are encountering?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I was looking for a more global way without the need of specify the name of the user. A sort of global method that will give me all names of each user at once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do it in the object itself, use a class variable in conjunction with a static method:

```
class Bacheca:

    created_users = []

    def __init__(self, name, surname, value):
        self.name = name
        self.surname = surname
        self.value = value
        Bacheca.created_users.append(self)

    @staticmethod
    def created():
        return Bacheca.created_users

user1 = Bacheca("John", "Black", 1)
user2 = Bacheca("Mark", "Green", 2)
user3 = Bacheca("Phil", "White", 3)
print([user.name for user in Bacheca.created()])
```

Output:

```
['John', 'Mark', 'Phil']
```

Every time `__init__` is called (for initialisation of a new instance), the created object will be appended to `created_users`, which is a variable of the *class*, as opposed to an *instance*. Therefore, it persistently holds a reference to every instance that has been created.

You could add more bells and whistles by, say, overriding `__del__`, but that is probably beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: This is almost always a bad idea and a sign you need to get used to organizing your objects with data structures instead of just assigning everything to a variable, though.

Comment: Also, overriding `__del__` will be useless, because the class variable keeps every instance alive until program shutdown.

Comment: @user2357112 If I really were to add support for that, I would use `weakref`.

Comment: @user2357112 Can you be more specific? I'm new to classes and OOP in general so every suggestion it's gold for me. What I'm doing wrong? Thank you for your time.

Comment: @FedericoDiLembo If you just want to know what objects you have created, you should probably put them in a `list` after creation. The class should not, in general, know what instances have been made of it *unless* there is a good reason to do so.

Answer (score 1):

The other answer is creative solution that I may have a use for in the future but caution should be taken with it. As noted in the comments it will keep a reference to your class instances, thus the garbage collector won't delete them properly (i.e. none of the class instances will be deleted until the last instance is unused [even then it may act funky and not delete properly]).  There are ways around this (such as `weakref` or using the `__del__` magic method) but if you are more of a novice I would probably avoid it. If all you want is a list then make a list:

```
users = []
users.append(Bacheca("John", "Black", 1))
users.append(Bacheca("Mark", "Green", 2))
users.append(Bacheca("Phil", "White", 3))

for user in users:
    print(user.name)
# or
print([user.name for user in users])
```

Also if you aren't doing anything else with your class and you are just using it to group attributes together then you may want to use a `namedtuple`.

```
from collections import namedtuple
Bacheca = namedtuple('Bacheca', 'name surname value')

# it acts the same as your class
users = []
users.append(Bacheca("John", "Black", 1))
users.append(Bacheca("Mark", "Green", 2))
users.append(Bacheca("Phil", "White", 3))

for user in users:
    print(user.name)
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. I'm gonna look into namedtuple documentation.

Comment: I think that in that case, a `dataclass` would be preferable to a `namedtuple`.